# Magento Documentation Page broken

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was looking Magento SOAP API. But the page at `http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.level.html` seems to be broken. One can check the footer or some other content is not there. Where should I put forth this query?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing would be to either create an issue on github https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues and then maybe try to fix it yourself.

Looking at the source the footer is actually commented out `<?php include(__ROOT__ . 'footer.php'); ?>` but the actual page https://github.com/magento/devdocs/blob/develop/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.info.html isn't. It looks like a broken tag somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Please check the page now. I fixed the "Edit this page on GitHub" link to go to the correct file. I also commented out the footer.

Comment: You have added just "//"

Comment: That's what my text editor did when I commented out the line. Removed the footer entirely.